# How to know if a function is $C^1$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I have the following function:
$$f(x,y) = \begin{cases} 
\frac{1-e^{-x^2-y^2}}{x^2+y^2} & y<x^2\\
1& y\geq x^2
\end{cases}
$$

It’s in an exam and they give us several options. I already know that the function is continuos at $(0,0)$, the partial derivatives at $(0,0)$ are both $0$, and I’ve also proven by definition that the function is differentiable at that point. 
However, I have two options left and I have to know if the function is $C^1$ at $(0,0)$. 
I don’t know how to approach this part since I don’t known how to get an explicit formula for the partial derivatives.

Comment: What is your issue to get *explicit formula for the partial derivatives*?

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net I think that I never learnt how to do it. I tried doing it by definition in a general point $(x,y)$ but I don’t know which part of the function take in each term. Then I tried just doing the derivatives of each part but I don’t know if that’s right

Comment: You can compute the partial derivatives in $y < x^2$ and $y> x^2$ and then look at their conitnuity at the origin. Not fun computations... but it should work.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net Let me see if I get this right. For examples the partial derivative with respect of x. If $y>x^2$ I get that the derivative is 0. And if $y>x^2$ it’s $\frac{2xe^{-x^2-y^2}(x^2+y^2)-2x(1-e^{-x^2-y^2})}{(x^2+y^2)^2}$ I know that the first one is continuos at (0,0) but what about the second one? Since it’s not defined at that point.

Comment: Your computation looks good. You then have to study the difference with $\partial_x(0,0)$ and prove that this difference goes to zero when $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ goes to zero.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net I think I didn’t get it. What do yo mean with the difference? And I have to divide it by $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ ? And I have a question. The point $(0,0)$ satisfies $y \geq x^2$ so $\partial_x (0,0) = 0$ Isn’t it enough to prove that the the limit with $(x,y)\to (0,0)$ of the other derivative (the one that I wrote in the previous comment) is $0 = \partial_x(0,0) $ to prove that $\partial_x(x,y)$ is continuos at $(0,0)$?

Comment: No, you don't have to divide by $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$. You have to prove that $\vert \partial_x(x,y) - \partial_x(0,0) \vert \to 0$ as $\sqrt{x^2+y^2} \to 0$.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net Ohh ok. And what about the other thing that I mention? Will it be enough to prove that the limit of the “difficult” derivative is $\partial_x(0,0)$ ?

Answer (score 1):

On and above the parabola $y=x^2$ we have $f(x,y)\equiv1$. For a given $x\ne0$ one has
$$\lim_{y\nearrow x^2} f(x,y)={1-e^{-x^2-x^4}\over x^2+x^4}<1\ ,$$
because ${1-e^{-t}\over t}<1$ for $t>0$. This shows that $f$ is not continuous on the parabola $y=x^2$, except at $(0,0)$. It follows that $f$ is not differentiable in a full neighborhood of $(0,0)$, and so it cannot be $C^1$ at $(0,0)$.

Comment: Thanks, I understand what you said. However, can you help me understand why the following is wrong? If I calculate the derivatives with respect to $x$ when $y<x^2$ i get a certain formula, and then if a calculate the limit when $(x,y) \to (0,0)$ I get $0$ that is exactly $\partial_x(0,0)$. Doesn’t that mean that the derivative is continuos?

Comment: Your derivatives are undefined at all points $\ne(0,0)$ of the parabola $y=x^2$. How could they be continuous at $(0,0)$ in such a case?